# Using SUM with a switch function in Report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement

I have a column of data called Date and I am using that to perform a switch. Basically the figure needs to be 120 on a weekday and 0 on a weekend so I have used.

```
    =SWITCH
(Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "1", "0",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "2", "120",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "3", "120",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "4", "120",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "5", "120",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "6", "120",
 Weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = "7", "0"

)
```

Which works great. However I also want a Total at the bottom of the sheet. I (somewhat naively) tried adding

```
=SUM( ... )
```

to the expression but that resulted in an #Error in the textbox. I also tried

```
=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox85.value)
```

and that didn't even run throwing the error

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   'Textbox84.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a
>   report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items
>   contained in page headers and footers.

So my question is how do I sum up this switch function or do I need to rethink this? I guess functionally all I really need is count of the total weekdays so far "this" month (that stays accurate no matter what month is picked using the date parameters). I can then * that number by 120.

Comment: The switch expression could have been added as a calculated field to your dataset. Then you can Sum the field in your report as you normally would. It's generally not a good idea to refer to textboxes in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

So I came at it from a different angle and tried a SQL based solution. I added a column with the code

```
,CASE
    WHEN 
    DATEPART(dw,convert(date,format(dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103)) in (1,7)
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    End as [weekday]
```

Then used

```
=Fields!weekday.Value*120
```

in my textbox and

```
=Sum(Fields!weekday.Value, "DataSet1")*120
```

in my total. Got the desired results.